# Password protect a controller without Identity/Membership

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way in asp.net core 2 to protect a controller I have called AdminController that will require a username/password that i set in appsettings.json instead of having to use the membership/identity tables?
The controller for Admin will ever only be used by one user and the password can be static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would recommend using better authentication methods (authentication middleware or such like) you could add a class and use ConfigureServices in Startup with dependency injection to get what you're after.

Below is a rough outline of how it could be done. I haven't tested it so it may need modification.

**appsettings.json**

```
...
"AdminLogin": {
    "userName": "Admin",
    "password": "secretsquirrel"
},
....
```

**Model:**

```
public class AdminLogin
{
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServies(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.Configure<AdminLogin>(Configuration.GetSection("AdminLogin"));
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class AdminController
{
    public AdminLogin adminLogin { get; }
    public AdminController(IOptions<AdminLogin> adminLogin)
    {
        this.adminLogin = adminLogin.Value;
    }

    public string Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        if(userName == adminLogin.userName && password == adminLogin.password)
        {
             return "Woo logged in";
        }
        else "Incorrect username and/or password";
    }
}
```